# Does picking up food do anything?

Tags: i-am-bread

In I Am Bread, various food items (such as baked beans, jelly, and licorice) can be picked up by moving over them, at which point they will stick there. I've tried this on several levels, but I don't notice any change. Does picking up food change anything, or is it just an effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some food will change the way your bread behaves on surfaces.

Butter makes your bread incredibly slippery, allowing you to glide across surfaces easily, at the cost of having greatly reduced traction.

Jam/Jelly makes you sticky, which makes it slightly harder for your bread to flip over, but also makes you slide down the wall more slowly, allowing you to regain some grip.

Various other foods can get stuck to your bread as well, which increase the surface area of your bread and makes it slightly more difficult to move around.  Though I haven't noticed any benefit to having this food on you yet, these foods along seem to improve your rank at the end of a level.  Butter and Jam also seem to improve your score if you finish a level with them.

There is also a special Super Jelly that you can get if you fail a level too many times - it will appear near the loaf where your bread spawns, and if you touch it, you will be immune to losing your edibility.